# How do I generate a new quiz every time the page is refreshed?

Tags: php, jquery, random

I am making a website and it is going to have a quiz which is going to be some multiple choice questions and I want to know if there is a way that I can just make a list of several questions and everytime someone clicks on "take the Test" it generates a new quiz with a mix of all of the questions? Also I want to make sure that I am not using the same question more than once? How can I go about doing this? Keep in mind I am not an advanced web developer or anything so if you would, please keep the answers clear and concise. Anyways, what I was planning on doing and have been doing for the past few weeks is using the PHP rand function and just making a set of a few quizes and whenever the page is refresh it chooses a number between (1,15) and I was creating a quiz for each number with the Id of 1,2,3,etc but that is a lot of work and I feel there is a better and much easier way to do this.

Please tell me if there is an easier way to do this (using only PHP would also be nice). Thank you!

Comment: Put the questions (or some identifier) in an array, shuffle the array, and take the first n items.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have a table of questions, what you'll want to do is select all the ids from the table and store them in an variable called $AllQuestionIds, so the variable should look like this,

```
$AllQuestionIds = [
    [0] => ['id' => 1],
    [1] => ['id' => 2],
    [2] => ['id' => 3]
]
```

Then when you run shuffle on $AllQuestionIds, your array should look like this,

```
$AllQuestionIds = [
    [0] => ['id' => 2],
    [1] => ['id' => 3],
    [2] => ['id' => 1]
]
```

Afterwards, for the remainder of the quiz, you'll want to store this array in session, then when the users click next question, pull the next id from the array, retrieve the question and display it.